# Declaring variables inside Shiny application in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application, where i take some input from the user, which should serve as arguments for some functions to be served on he backend.

in my UI on the home page, i have a textInput, which should be served as a global variable (because it should be used in almost all functions).

but as far as i have tried there is NO way to declare a function inside the server function.

Sample code:

UI component

```
  textInput(inputId = "app_name", label="Please enter the name of your application", value="app_x")
))
```

```
#this is declared as a global variable in the top
application_name <- NULL
...
#inside server function
application_name <<- input$app_name
```

causes this error:
`Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

Comment: You need to wrap your call in a reactive expression (observeEvent or something like that)

Comment: thank you, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with this error several times. In most cases it's caused because Shiny has no way of knowing which value this is. For example:

in ui.R:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 textInput("text","Text")
 actionButton("button","Submit")
)
```

in server.R:

```
  observeEvent(input$button,{
     result <- yourFunction(input$text$value)
  })
```

If you need to use this value as a variable (Not as the argument of a function), you can also use what you where using, but it needs to be inside a reactive event (observeEvent, reactiveValue, etc.)

in server.R:

```
  observeEvent(input$button,{
     neededText <- input$text$value
     .... Do what you need with the text....
  })
```

In your specific case, you can pass the variable as an argument to the functions when a specific event occurs (Since I don't know what your app does)

**EDIT:** 
You can also use reactive as so:

in server.R:

```
  text_reactive <- reactive({
    input$text
  })
```

Comment: How do i know what event that is, like for example a textField, would that be on change for example? Button on click etc?

Comment: One more question, how can this data, be accessed globally? If i declare a variable inside an `observeEvent` ?

Comment: @baileyhaldwin You can use eventReactive to not declare inside a function `yourVar<-eventReactive(input$text, { input$text})`

Comment: okay so far, i have made the solution, using a global variable and just assigning that, the problem with that solution, is that it is not changeble after it is initially sat...

Comment: @baileyhaldwin Did you see my edit? Maybe using `reactive` would be better for you. I don't know what you want to achieve with your global variable, the main solutions are those i think.